# Python ArgumentParser strips with space and dash

Tags: python, command-line-arguments, argparse

I need to get the complete string inside quotes as an argument (Possible to use only argparse).But it will stop at space and dash and strips other words in quotes.
Please help to sole this.

Code :

```
from argparse import ArgumentParser,ArgumentError
parser=ArgumentParser(usage='test.py help',prog='test')

parser.add_argument('-c','--cmd', nargs='+',type=str,action='store',dest='build_cmd',
                    help='Mandatory.)
parser.add_argument('-l','--build-mode',action='store_true',default=False,
                    help='Optional.)


if options.build_cmd:
  build_cmd = ' '.join(options.build_cmd)
  print(build_cmd)
```

```
python test.py -c 'build run test' -l  # works fine
python test.py -c 'build -P test' -l   # get only "build" and strip others
```

Comment: I can't reproduce the problem. There are some mistakes in the code but when I fix those (add a closing quote after `help='Mandatory.'`, another closing quote after `help='Optional.'`, and creating the `options` object with `options = parser.parse_args()` before the `if`) then the second test case prints `build -P test` as expected.

Comment: Check `sys.argv` to see the list of strings that the parser has to work with.

Comment: With the right quotes and OS shell, 'build -P test' should be a single string, and argument for 'c', just as in the other test.  You might want to drop the `nargs='+' if you are always quoting the single string argument.